# Extend a custom jQuery event callback?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have this custom plugin event callback which is triggered on all pages:

```
$(document).on('pjax:complete', all.myfunction);
```

I'd like to extend `myfunction`: calling `all.myfunction` and then specific code:

```
//  my specific page  
$(document).on('pjax:complete', specific.myfunction);

specific.myfunction = function() { 
    all.myfunction();
    /* code relative to this specific page */
}
```

Is there any cleaner approach to achieve this?

Comment: You still want the behavior of `all.myfunction` to apply?

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm talking about extending :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want extra functionality, you can just add a new handler. It won't overwrite existing handlers

```
$(document).on('pjax.complete', specific.myfunction);
```

One detail is that there's no guarantee that handlers are called in a specific order, even though in practice, they're called in the order they were installed. So if you need to guarantee the first handler is called first, you have to do the following.

```
$(document).off('pjax.complete', all.myfunction);
$(document).on('pjax.complete', function() {
    all.myfunction();
    specific.myfunction();
});
```